# Extract QoS Buffer Drops via SNMP

Tags: snmp, qos, monitoring

I am in the process of rolling out ***solarwinds*** for visibility of QoS performance using ***netflow*** and ***CBQOS*** to show ***QoS*** class usage. One thing I am unsure of is what type of monitoring is available on L2 edge switches. We have a QoS policy configured and can see port / buffer drops via CLI using `"Switch#sh mls qos int gi1/0/1 statistics"` but what I would like to do is extract this port data to Solarwinds via SNMP so its visible to all. Is there a specific MIB available which would provide this functionality? More specifically I would like to see output queue drops.

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for interface output queue drops, you can use the cportQosDropPkts OID (part of [CISCO-PORT-QOS-MIB](ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/v2/CISCO-PORT-QOS-MIB.my)).

```
$ snmptranslate -On CISCO-PORT-QOS-MIB:cportQosDropPkts
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.189.1.3.2.1.7
```

If you have a CCO you can look up the [OID details here](http://snmp.cloudapps.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=cportQosDropPkts&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT).

> The count of dropped packets as the result of queuing and scheduling
>   related QoS features that  can produce drops.

This OID shows a depricated, but it should work on the platforms that you've listed in your comment to @Raul D.

#### Additional required MIB files:

[CISCO-QOS-PIB-MIB.txt](ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/v2/CISCO-PORT-QOS-MIB.my)

[CISCO-SMI.txt](ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/v2/CISCO-SMI.my)

[CISCO-TC.txt](ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/v2/CISCO-TC.my)

[CISCO-VTP-MIB.txt](ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/v2/CISCO-VTP-MIB.my)

#### Example using snmpwalk and bash on a C3560:

```
$ snmpwalk -v2c -c community 127.0.0.1 CISCO-PORT-QOS-MIB:cportQosDropPkts
CISCO-PORT-QOS-MIB::cportQosDropPkts.10020.ingress.1 = Counter64: 0 packets
CISCO-PORT-QOS-MIB::cportQosDropPkts.10020.egress.1 = Counter64: 913 packets

$ ./cportQosDropPkts.sh -c community -h 127.0.0.1

Interface Name          Output Queue Drops

--------------          ------------------
FastEthernet0/1         0
FastEthernet0/2         0
FastEthernet0/3         0
FastEthernet0/4         0
FastEthernet0/5         0
FastEthernet0/6         0
FastEthernet0/7         0
FastEthernet0/8         0
FastEthernet0/9         0
FastEthernet0/10        0
FastEthernet0/11        0
FastEthernet0/12        0
FastEthernet0/13        0
FastEthernet0/14        0
FastEthernet0/15        0
FastEthernet0/16        0
FastEthernet0/17        0
FastEthernet0/18        0
FastEthernet0/19        0
FastEthernet0/20        916
FastEthernet0/21        0
FastEthernet0/22        0
FastEthernet0/23        0
FastEthernet0/24        0
GigabitEthernet0/1      0
GigabitEthernet0/2      0


$ ./cportQosDropPkts.sh -c community -h 127.0.0.1 -i FastEthernet0/20

Interface Name          Output Queue Drops

--------------          ------------------
FastEthernet0/20        916
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cisco MIB locator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/MainServlet):

- [For 3560 using 12.2(58)SE2](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/MainServlet?ReleaseSel=2904&PlatformSel=362&fsSel=852)
- [For 3750 using 12.2(58)SE2](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/MainServlet?ReleaseSel=2904&PlatformSel=371&fsSel=748)
- [For 2960s using 15.2(2)E](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/MainServlet?ReleaseSel=4158&PlatformSel=354&fsSel=1410)
- [For 2960x using 15.2(2)E](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/MainServlet?ReleaseSel=4158&PlatformSel=357&fsSel=1410)

This [Cisco technote](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/119031-technote-router-00.html) can also help you

Comment: a range of 3560, 3750,2960, 2960s & 2960X